# MySQL install is broken, cant install

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, service, apt

My MySQL community install was broken, so i reinstalled it. Now, it won't install at all. Help!
This is the output when running `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

```
Setting up mysql-client-5.7 (5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/logrotate.d/mysql-server ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/mysql/debian-start ...
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
ERROR: Unable to start MySQL server:
mysqld: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/' (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
2020-03-24T11:41:39.379271Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1-log) starting as process 1856 ...
2020-03-24T11:41:39.381242Z 0 [ERROR] You have enabled the binary log, but you haven't provided the mandatory server-id. Please refer to the proper server start-up parameters documentation
2020-03-24T11:41:39.381859Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2020-03-24T11:41:39.381970Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
Please take a look at https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/MySQL/FAQ for tips on fixing common upgrade issues.
Once the problem is resolved, run apt-get --fix-broken install to retry.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-5.7 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.39) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@honeyfrost:/# apt-get --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
ERROR: Unable to start MySQL server:
mysqld: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/' (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
2020-03-24T11:42:48.824469Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1-log) starting as process 2754 ...
2020-03-24T11:42:48.827477Z 0 [ERROR] You have enabled the binary log, but you haven't provided the mandatory server-id. Please refer to the proper server start-up parameters documentation
2020-03-24T11:42:48.828517Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2020-03-24T11:42:48.828544Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
Please take a look at https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/MySQL/FAQ for tips on fixing common upgrade issues.
Once the problem is resolved, run apt-get --fix-broken install to retry.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-5.7 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

If i then run `sudo systemctl start mysql`, this comes up:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

And if i check the status by doing `sudo systemctl status mysql`, this comes up:

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-03-24 12:46:55 CET; 1min 2s ago
  Process: 2930 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 24 12:46:55 honeyfrost systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Mar 24 12:46:55 honeyfrost systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Mar 24 12:46:55 honeyfrost systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Mar 24 12:46:55 honeyfrost systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Mar 24 12:46:55 honeyfrost systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 24 12:46:55 honeyfrost systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

I've searched on google for hours now, but I can't find anything that works. I've tried deleting all folders associated with mysql, but the problem still persists! Help please

EDIT: When doing `sudo apt-get purge *mariadb*`, I get an error when trying to purge mariadb-server-10.4

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mariadb-server-10.4*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 131562 files and directories currently installed.)
Purging configuration files for mariadb-server-10.4 (1:10.4.12+maria~bionic) ...
find: ‘/var/lib/mysql’: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server-10.4 (--purge):
 installed mariadb-server-10.4 package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mariadb-server-10.4
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Are you installing MYSQL or mariaDB?

Comment: I am installing MySQL

Comment: Then this looks odd `mysqld: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/'`

Comment: Well, it is what comes up when i run `apt-get install mysql-server`

Comment: Try to purge all packages related to mysql or mariadb. (Make sure to keep your database or a backup.) Do you have a local installation that was not installed from an Ubutu/Debian package?

Comment: I get an error when trying to purge mariadb-server-10.4, so I can't remove it. I'll edit in the output in the post